# How to use Uglify.js to concat JavaScript for each view in Express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, uglifyjs

So, I have a website built on express.js and I'm hoping to use uglify.js to manage some javascripts in my build process.

A typical view of mine looks like this:

```
extend layout
  block head
    script(src="/js/polyfills/html5shiv.js")
  block body
    header
      nav...
    main
      section
      form...
    footer
      nav...
    script(src="/js/polyfills/arrayGenerics.js")
    script(src="/js/polyfills/placeholder.js")
    script(src="/js/formSubmitter.js")
```

Ideally, the JavaScript file at the top would be minified, and the ones at the bottom would be concatenated into one and minified.

I know how to do that on the command line, and I can use npm scripts to "automate" a bit, but how do I deal with editing this view file? And all the rest of my view files? Then, how do I get things back the way they were so I can continue development?

I'm used to stylus and the way it handles similar issues with css, ultimately producing one beautiful .css file and working nicely on the fly, but javascript seems a bit different, and I'm not quite sure how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set uglify up to concatenate everything into a single file or separate files, using gulp.  Ideally if you know you have JS files 1, 2, & 3 at the top of the page and 4 at the bottom, you can set it up to concatenate 1, 2, & 3 together and just minify file 4.

Gulp file would look something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
// Process scripts and concatenate them into one output file
gulp.task('topScripts', ['clean'], function() {
 gulp.src(paths.scripts, {cwd: bases.app})
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(concat('top.js'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'js/'));
});
gulp.task('botScripts', ['clean'], function() {
 gulp.src(paths.scripts, {cwd: bases.app})
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(concat('bot.js'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'js/'));
});
```

Where you have previously defined top and bottom scripts.

Comment: I don't really use gulp or grunt. Here's why: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/